# Why does xcode want me to make navigationController an optional when I have a default ?? value just after

Tags: swift, xcode, option-type

In the fourth line, xcode try to force me to add a `?` after navigationController, even if I have a default value destinationViewController with the `??`
And if I add the `?` it wants me to change the `if let` syntax with a `in` instead of a `as`...

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var destinationViewController = segue.destination
    if let navigationViewController = destinationViewController as? UINavigationController {
        destinationViewController = navigationController.visibleViewController ?? destinationViewController
    }
```

Comment: On a side note: `destinationViewController = navigationController.visibleViewController ?? destinationViewController` statement has no meaning.

Comment: It actually does have a meaning. It is shorthand for safely optional unwrapping `navigationController.visibleViewController` and only assigning its value to `destinationViewController` if the unwrapping succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var destinationViewController = segue.destination
    if let navigationViewController = destinationViewController as? UINavigationController {
        destinationViewController = navigationViewController.visibleViewController ?? destinationViewController
    }
```

You use *navigationController* instead of *navigation**View**Controller*